# Intersection of two arrays in multiple arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm searching for a way for extracting common values in at least two arrays in the list of arrays in JS.

e.g. `[["google", "amazon", "reddit"], ["telegram", "reddit", "discord"], ["firefox", "telegram", "chrome"]]` to `["reddit", "telegram]`

The point is 1. the arrays can be any length 2. common at least two (or any specified number) of arrays but not all of the arrays.

I looked a countless numbers of SO posts and also looked the lodash functions, they are all talking either "of two arrays" or "of all arrays from multiple arrays", none of them were takling "of two/arbitrary arrays from multiple arrays". So I'm here to ask.

Thanks.

Comment: `[...new Set(input.flat())].map(_=>[_,input.flat().filter($=>$===_).length]).filter(([,_])=>_>1).map(([_])=>_)`

Comment: @JaromandaX Is that written in [BrainFuck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck) ? ;) - this will find common values in the same sub array too

Comment: @mplungjan BF does not include a-z, so no ... it was written to work as a one-liner (my favourite type of code), with minimal help for a 5 year veteran of SO who couldn't even bother writing any code :p

Comment: @mplungjan *this will find common values in the same sub array too* - it will also find values that are in ALL arrays (which it shouldn't if you read the OP) ... both *issues* are very easily remedied

Comment: @mplungjan - `[...new Set(input.map(_=>[...new Set(_)]).flat())].map(_=>[_,input.map(_=>[...new Set(_)]).flat().filter($=>$===_).length]).filter(([,_])=>_>1&&_<input.length).map(([_])=>_)` :p

Comment: I made an O(n) version which is not a one liner but more efficient and easier on the eye

Comment: @JaromandaX You should answer and give the reasons for the two versions

Comment: I have posted an answer - with meaningful easier on the eye code :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using various Array methods, and `Set`, it can be accomplished fairly easily

```js
const input = [["google", "amazon", "reddit"], ["telegram", "reddit", "discord"], ["firefox", "telegram", "chrome"]];

// remove duplicaates within a sub array
const uniqueInSub = input.map(_=>[...new Set(_)]);

// create a list of all values in a flat array
const uniqueInSubFlat = uniqueInSub.flat();

// list of unique values
const values = [...new Set(uniqueInSubFlat)];

// array of [value, count] pairs
const pre1 = values.map(value => [ value, uniqueInSubFlat.filter(subValue => subValue === value).length]);

// value,count pairs where the count > 1 and < the number of sub arrays
const pre2 = pre1.filter(([, count]) => count > 1 && count < input.length);

// array of values
const result = pre2.map(([value])=>value);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: @Yunnosch - what is a s**m question and wtf does it have to do with me?

Answer (score 0):

```js
let arr = [["google", "amazon", "reddit"], ["telegram", "reddit", "discord"], ["firefox", "telegram", "chrome"]]

const flatedArr =arr.flat(Infinity);

const repeatedItems = []
const nonRepeatedItems = []

flatedArr.forEach(val => {

  if(nonRepeatedItems.includes(val))
   return repeatedItems.push(val)
   
  return nonRepeatedItems.push(val)
})

console.log(repeatedItems);  // ["reddit","telegram"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an O(n) version using Map to not bother about the type of the values

Note this will also return dupes in one array

```js
const extractCommonValues = arr => {
  const counts = arr.flat().reduce((acc, cur) => (acc.set(cur, (acc.get(cur) || 0) + 1), acc), new Map());
  return [...counts.keys()].filter(el => counts.get(el) > 1);
};

console.log(
extractCommonValues([["google", "amazon", "reddit"], ["telegram", "reddit", "discord"], ["firefox", "telegram", "chrome"]])
)

// will extract the dupe amazon in the first array
console.log(
extractCommonValues([["google", "amazon", "reddit", "amazon"], ["telegram", "reddit", "discord"], ["firefox", "telegram", "chrome"]])
)
```

To ignore dupes in the sub arrays we can set them first

```js
const extractCommonValues = arr => {
  const counts = arr.map(subArr => [...new Set(subArr)]).flat().reduce((acc, cur) => (acc.set(cur, (acc.get(cur) || 0) + 1), acc), new Map());
  return [...counts.keys()].filter(el => counts.get(el) > 1);
};

console.log(
  extractCommonValues([["google", "amazon", "reddit", "amazon"], ["telegram", "reddit", "discord"], ["firefox", "telegram", "chrome"]])
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function findCommonValues(arrays, minCommon) {
  // Create an object to keep track of the count of each value
  const countMap = new Map();
  
  // Iterate over each array
  for (const array of arrays) {
    // Iterate over each value in the array
    for (const value of array) {
      // Increment the count for the current value
      countMap.set(value, (countMap.get(value) || 0) + 1);
    }
  }
  
  // Filter the values that have a count equal to or greater than the specified minimum
  const commonValues = [];
  for (const [value, count] of countMap.entries()) {
    if (count >= minCommon) {
      commonValues.push(value);
    }
  }
  
  return commonValues;
}

// Example usage
const arrays = [
  ["google", "amazon", "reddit"],
  ["telegram", "reddit", "discord"],
  ["firefox", "telegram", "chrome"]
];

const commonValues = findCommonValues(arrays, 2);
console.log(commonValues); // Output: ["reddit", "telegram"]
```

Comment: Hi, You may consider the time complexity here which is  O(n * m + k + u), where n represents the number of arrays, m represents the maximum number of values in any array, k represents the total number of values in all arrays, and u represents the number of unique values in all arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `.flat()` and `.filter()` methods as follows:

```js
const 
      data = [["google", "amazon", "reddit"], ["telegram", "reddit", "discord"], ["firefox", "telegram", "chrome"]],
      
      common = [...new Set(data.flat().filter((v,i,a) => a.filter(val => val === v).length > 1))];
          
console.log( common );
```

**Or More efficiently ....**

```js
const 
      data = [["google", "amazon", "reddit"], ["telegram", "reddit", "discord"], ["firefox", "telegram", "chrome"]],
      
      all = data.flat(),
      
      uniq = [...new Set(all)],
      
      common = uniq.filter(v => all.filter(val => val === v).length > 1);
          
console.log( common );
```